# What exactly happened in the last episode of Rick and Morty season 5?

Tags: rick-and-morty

I just finished watching Rick and Morty season 5 and I'm not sure what

> Evil Morty

does at the end of the episode.

To me it seems that

> he broke the multiverse that Ricks builded in order to live free of this toxic relationship, and opened the path to a new one, as seen with his new yellow portal gun.

Is my understanding correct ? If so what will be the repercusion of this act on the R&M multiverse ?

Comment: Yeah, you saw what I saw. We'll find out in like six years or so.... J/k, release date for S6 is June 2022. *100 call-backs. Rick and Morty Forever, With the Call-backs. 1000 times the call-backs. Call-backs to other call-backs. 100 (burp) years of call-backs. Calling all cal-backs back! Wubalubadubdub, Ooowee!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as what happened, I think you got the gist of it. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_and_Morty_(season_5)#Episodes):

> Evil Morty... used brain scans taken from Rick to create a path outside of the Central Finite Curve, a walled off portion of the multiverse where Rick is the smartest man alive and restricts the ones where he is not... Evil Morty successfully escapes and steps into a gold portal to an unknown destination.

A similar synopsis can be found on [fandom](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Rickmurai_Jack#Synopsis):

> President Morty uses his machine to tear open the Curve and launch himself through it in a small spaceship. Coming out on the other side, he sees the rest of the universe and smiles, opening a gold portal with an improved gun and stepping through it.

As for what the repercussions will be for the R&M universe, I believe we'll have to wait for future seasons to answer that question. [Inside the Episode](https://youtu.be/htSNvtqat7o) didn't really seem to offer any further insight. Nerdist tries to [explain](https://nerdist.com/article/rick-and-morty-season-5-finale-explained/) the finale, but like us they don't actually know what happens to Evil Morty:

> The show could also explore what lies beyond the Central Finite Curve. Evil Morty is gone, and we might never see him again. But if we do, what is the multiverse like without Rick as its ultimate genius? What’s life like for a Morty totally free of his grandfather? If the show ever travels back to that beautiful universe on the other side, it will likely be totally different from what we’ve seen before.

Comment: I'll wait a bit to mark it as the answer but this seems correct to me !